# unable to locate appropriate constructor on class expected arguments are: java.util.collection

Tags: java, hibernate

I am trying to select list using multiselect from criteria api.

My code looks like:

model:

```
@Data
@NoArgsConstructor
@AllArgsConstructor
public class Data {
   private List<SubData> datas = new ArrayList<>();
}
```

repo:

```
// all staffs like criteriabuilder, criteriaquery and joins

query.multiselect(root.get(Data_.DATAS));
```

and I got:

unable to locate appropriate constructor on class expected arguments are: java.util.collection

Answer (score 0):

Your Lombok `@AllArgsConstructor` annotation creates a constructor with a parameter `java.util.List`, while Hibernate expects a class with a constructor receiving `java.util.Collection`. So, there is a type mismatch, thus Hibernate can't find the right constructor.

Please, add the appropriate constructor, and the problem will be fixed. Most likely, another collection type is used in your mapping for this field.